# Can I easily replace the hard drive of my PS3?

Tags: ps3, hard-drive

Is it easier to replace the internal hard drive of a PS3, or to go with an external hard drive?

Answer (score 0):

It is *easier* to go with an external hard drive. That just involves plugging it in to the USB ports on your console and formatting it with the existing console OS.

However, installing a new hard drive isn't particularly complex. For most (all?) models of PS3 it's just a couple of screws, but it will mean a more-lengthy setup to install the software onto the console which involves downloading the OS onto a USB stick and going through several reboot cycles.

The PS3 also seemed, to me, fairly slow to create a partition for itself compared to trying to do the same thing on a PC. But my PS3 is one of the older models so I'm not sure if it's just showing its age.

Also, in the end result, I believe an internal drive will perform better (being connected via SATA) compared to an external USB-connected drive.